# Returning complex model table data to the controller using ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Here's my scenario. I have a Model that contains a List of objects with additional view attributes and an Entity attribute. A view containing this model iterates through the list building up the table rows from the object attributes.

Model

```
public class DownloadableFileGroupViewModel
{
    public List<DownloadableFileViewModel> Files { get; set; }
}
```

List Object

```
public class DownloadableFileViewModel
{
    public DownloadableFile File { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Entity

```
public class DownloadableFile
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Display( Name="File" )]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int DownloadableFileGroupID { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a snippet from the view that builds the table,
http://codeshare.io/ks8c1

Finally, a simple Post function in my controller:

```
public ActionResult ImageDownloadArea(DownloadableFileGroupViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that models.Files in my controller is always null. How should I be structuring my form so that the model binder rebuilds the model and serves it to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `HttpPostedFileBase` instead of `DownloadableFileGroupViewModel` in controller.

```
public ActionResult ImageDownloadArea( IEnumerable < HttpPostedFileBase > model )

{
   return View( model );
}
```

Also change enctype = "multipard/form-data" to enctype = "multipart/form-data" in your view.

Try to use List in your view as Model. Also include "Selected" Property in DownloadableFile class.

Comment: Hi there the the DownloadableFile class is an Entity that represents a table structure so I believe it should not contain "Selected", thus wrapping it in a ViewModel is a good practice as it separates "Interface" from "Domain". Also the user is not selecting a file so HttpPostedFileBase does not help me. This is table population with a extra tick box. Thanks for the comment though